# Localhost error code : 200 | Error in processing request (It seems like the connection to server has been lost.)

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost, opera

```
phpMyAdmin 7.3.11
XAMPP (Apache, MySQL:3306)
Browser : Opera
```

I imported the database from remote server to the local.

Everything is fine on the remote server but on the local server, I am receiving this server error with error code 200.

> Error in processing request
>   Error code  200
>   Error text: Ok (rejected)
>   It seems that the connection to server has been lost.
>   Please check your network connectivity and server status.

In the local server, I am able to view all the database tables but I am not able to modify them.

On connecting the android app with local sever I am not able to fetch data from the local server.

**Server Log**

```
2019-12-04 17:17:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 191204 17:17:56
2019-12-04 17:18:08 11 [Warning] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2019-12-04 17:18:08 13 [Warning] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2019-12-04 17:18:08 15 [Warning] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

[image: Local Server error]

Comment: Remove your image, add textual error information into your question

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have addes error logs information now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using **Opera** browser, but it doesn't show any errors on **Chrome** and it is working fine now. Turns out the header content for finding the opera browser is missing in the Apache environment. So, the **localhost/phpmyadmin** will work fine on Chrome , safari and firefox.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I followed this Symfony bug solution:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/8e34978e4e2c4bf7dac97e44e904368c4cfb54f8 and made the modification (add array_value) on usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php and everything work now!

Open the ContainerBuilder.php file in directory
"/usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/",
and change this line:
$service = null === $r->getConstructor() ? $r->newInstance() : $r->newInstanceArgs($arguments);
into this:
$service = null === $r->getConstructor() ? $r->newInstance() : $r->newInstanceArgs(array_values($arguments));

Answer (score 0):

This is may be due to memory limit, try increasing memory limit.

Comment: Hello technos, could you please continue your answer by adding some reference to your suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was the problemin your sql serve, but I changed memory_limit to -1 in php.ini file after restart your xampp serve. And now check the problem is fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here! I was using Chrome and I tried to open PhpMyAdmin in another browser (Firefox) and it was working correctly! All that I had to do was to reset all the settings of Chrome; "Settings>Advanced>System>Restore settings to their original defaults."

And after that everything was working properly!

(Edit: Before the solution I tried to change the memory limit but without success, and from what I know you should not change it to -1. This sets memory limit to infinity which is a high security risk.)

Answer (score 0):

Check your cookies in your browser settings. if the cookies are blocked, then this type of issues comes. Allow all cookies and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exactly same problem on my firefox browser. I solved it immediately after clear site cookie and data.